# How can I fix this null pointer exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a `nullPointerException` and the rest of my code won't run. I have two classes setup. One is the `SalesPerson` and the other contains the `main` method. Line 42 is marked and that is where the `nullPointerException` occurs.

This is line 42

```
System.out.printf("%-20s %15.2f %14.2f %n", list[i].getFirstName()  + " " + list[i].getLastName(), list[i].getTotalSales(), list[i].getSalary());





public class SalesPerson {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double firstSales;
    private double secondSales;
    private double thirdSales;
    private double fourthSales;
    private double totalSales;
    private double salary;

    public SalesPerson(String lastName, String firstName, double firstSales,
            double secondSales, double thirdSales, double fourthSales,
            double totalSales, double salary) {

        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.firstSales = firstSales;
        this.secondSales = secondSales;
        this.thirdSales = thirdSales;
        this.fourthSales = fourthSales;
        this.totalSales = totalSales;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getTotalSales() {
        return totalSales;
    }

    public void setTotalSales(double totalSales) {
        this.totalSales = totalSales;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public double getFirstSales() {
        return firstSales;
    }

    public void setFirstSales(double firstSales) {

        if (firstSales >= 0) {
            this.firstSales = firstSales;
        } else {
            System.out.println("First sales must be greater than zero.");
        }
    }

    public double getSecondSales() {
        return secondSales;
    }

    public void setSecondSales(double secondSales) {
        if (secondSales >= 0) {
            this.secondSales = secondSales;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Second sales must be greater than zero.");
        }
    }

    public double getThirdSales() {
        return thirdSales;
    }

    public void setThirdSales(double thirdSales) {
        if (thirdSales >= 0) {
            this.thirdSales = thirdSales;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Third sales must be greater than zero.");
        }
    }

    public double getFourthSales() {
        return fourthSales;
    }

    public void setFourthSales(double fourthSales) {
        if (fourthSales >= 0) {
            this.fourthSales = fourthSales;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fourth sales must be greater than zero.");
        }
    }

}
```

SECOND CLASS

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Assignment10 {
        public static final int NUM_SALESPEOPLE = 20;
        public static final double NUM_PER_SALARY = 25;
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SalesPerson[] list = new SalesPerson[NUM_SALESPEOPLE];

            try {
                int people = 0;
                Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("A10.txt"));

                while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
                    String lastName = fileInput.next();
                    String firstName = fileInput.next();
                    double firstSales = fileInput.nextDouble();
                    double secondSales = fileInput.nextDouble();
                    double thirdSales = fileInput.nextDouble();
                    double fourthSales = fileInput.nextDouble();
                    double totalSales = firstSales + secondSales + thirdSales + fourthSales;
                    double salary = NUM_PER_SALARY * totalSales;
                    SalesPerson person = new SalesPerson(lastName, firstName,
                            firstSales, secondSales, thirdSales, fourthSales, totalSales, salary);
                    list[people] = person;
                    people++;

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error opening file.");
            }

            System.out.println("Full Name                Total Sales         Salary");
            System.out.println("=========                ===========         ======");
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SALESPEOPLE; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%-20s %15.2f %14.2f %n",      list[i].getFirstName()  + " " + list[i].getLastName(), list[i].getTotalSales(), list[i].getSalary());
            }
            System.out.println("===================================================");


        }

    }
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It happens at line 42, no where in the catch block.

Comment: list[i] is null, you expect to have 20 rows, how much do you load from file? Print i (in a separate statement) before your offending line and discover it :)

Comment: Have you tried to debug that particular line? You should be able to find the index where that's happening. Are you sure your `while loop ran 20 times?

Comment: probably you are adding less object than NUM_SALESPEOPLE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating an array of size 20. This array will hold only references to NULL. If in your file you have less than 20 entries you will end up with a nullpointerexception.

To be sure, try to print the value of people. If it less than 20 then this is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Your file 'A10.txt' doesn't have 20 (correct) lines.

You should not create an Array. Use `ArrayList` and `Iterator` instead and you won't have such problems.

Comment: Now, you've spoiled `Assignment20`. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a check for null:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SALESPEOPLE; i++) {
    if (list[i] != null) {
        System.out.printf("%-20s %15.2f %14.2f %n",      list[i].getFirstName()  + " " + list[i].getLastName(), list[i].getTotalSales(), list[i].getSalary());
    }
}
```

or declare

```
int people = 0;
```

two lines earlier (before your try-block) and use this number of actual read people as the upper bound in your for loop instead of `NUM_SALESPEOPLE`.